# For number of islands problem, my code keeps exceeding max recursion depth even though it looks the same as the solution. Can someone pinpoint error?

Tags: python

Link to problem:
Given an m x n 2D binary grid grid which represents a map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), return the number of islands.

An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

```
class Solution:
        def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:

            def flood(row,col):
                if row<0 or col<0 or row>=len(grid) or col>=len(grid[0]) or grid[row][col]=='0':
                    return

                grid[row][col]=='0'

                flood(row+1,col)
                flood(row-1,col)
                flood(row,col+1)
                flood(row,col-1)

                return 


            count = 0
            for row in range(len(grid)):
                for col in range(len(grid[0])):
                    if grid[row][col]=='1':
                        count+=1
                        flood(row,col)

            return count
```

Test case:
`[["1","1","1","1","0"],["1","1","0","1","0"],["1","1","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0","0"]]`

I feel my exit conditions look accurate and my numbers are quoted properly. I compared to the solution and it looks similar. The actual solution is posted below

```
def flood(i,j,grid):
    if i< 0 or j <0 or i >=len(grid) or j>=len(grid[i]):
        return
    elif grid[i][j] == '0':
        return
    grid[i][j] = '0'
    
    flood(i+1,j,grid) 
    flood(i,j+1,grid)  
    flood(i-1,j,grid)  
    flood(i,j-1,grid)  

class Solution(object):
    def numIslands(self, grid):
        """
        :type grid: List[List[str]]
        :rtype: int
        """
        
        count = 0
        
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[0])):
                if grid[i][j] == '1':
                    count+=1
                    flood(i, j, grid)
                    
        return count
```

The only difference i see is that the grid is passed in the recursive function, which i don't think should make a difference.

Comment: you should not assume everybody knows what the "number of islands problem" is. please at least provide a link...

Comment: apologies, here is the link: https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/

Comment: Your solution and the given solution traverse the space in a different order. That will lead to more or less recursion depending on the shape of the island.

Comment: It's easy to replace the recursion with a stack.

Comment: In your solution you don't set grid[row][col] to 0. You instead do `grid[row][col]=='0'` which is a comparison and not an assignment. the grid[row][col] doesn't change, and you end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah.  This seems really strange that the order in which you make the recursive calls matters.  As @PaulHankin says, you can just replace recursion with a set of points waiting to be flooded.  While the set is non-empty, pop one element off (x.pop()). If it's not-zero, set it to zero and add all its neighbors to the set.